# Why is an activation function notated as "g"?

Tags: deep-learning, notation, activation-function

In many cases an activation function is notated as `g` (e.g. Andrew Ng's Course courses), especially if it doesn't refer to any specific activation function such as sigmoid.

However, where does this convention come from? And for what reason did `g` start to be used?

Comment: It’s just a notation. You can call it whatever you want. a BC d

Comment: Yes but what is the reason? That is the point of my question.

Comment: Read some linear algebra.

Comment: That is not an answer.

Comment: ESL uses $\sigma(.)$.  This is a dumb question.

Comment: @generic_user What is ESL?

Comment: @Blaszard https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/

Comment: "Read some linear algebra", "ESL uses $\sigma$"... Those are dumb responses. 
I do agree that maybe the question could be more like: "What is the standard letter for the activation function and why?" And then talk about examples like ESL uses sigma and Andrew ng uses `g`, etc. Because not everyone uses g for the activation function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The addition of the activation layer creates a [composition of two functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition).

"A [general function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)), to be defined for a particular context, is usually denoted by a single letter, most often the lower-case letters f, g, h."

So it comes down to the reason that he uses the [hypothesis representation](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf) h(x)=wX+b which is a function, and that is wrapped by an activation function denoted as g. The choice of g seems to be purely alphabetical.

Comment: He didn't write the hypothesis function as `h`; he used `z`. So it was not intuitive for me why he used `g`...